# How do I call a Stimulus controller that's more than one word?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

So I've tried

```
{ controller: "reset_form", action: "turbo:submit-end->reset_form#reset" } 
{ controller: "reset-form", action: "turbo:submit-end->reset-form#reset" } 
{ controller: "reset_form", action: "turbo:submit-end->reset-form#reset" } 
{ controller: "reset-form", action: "turbo:submit-end->reset_form#reset" } 

With reset_form_controller.js, reset-form-controller.js, reset-form_controller.js...
```

Which all failed. Every single one-- I thought Stimulus just didn't work. Then I tried the base hello_controller.js example in my erb, and it did work. And yes, I did follow the hello_controller.js's guidelines(didn't work) and copied code LETTER FOR LETTER from hotwired.dev's showcase video(didn't work).

I ended up just changing it to reset_controller.js and doing

```
{ controller: "reset", action: "turbo:submit-end->reset#reset" }
```

to get it to work. But I'm still curious-- why did everything else fail? I feel my sanity slipping away. Out of all the things to be absolutely defeated by, it's trying to get a stimulus controller that's more than one word to run.

Comment: that is very strange. I have this bit of HTML `<button type="button" class="nav__login" data-controller="log_join" data-action="click->log_join#display">Join / Log in</button>` which properly direct to my `log_join_controller.js` file which is declared like ths in javascript/controllers/index : `import LogJoinController from "./log_join_controller"` `application.register("log_join", LogJoinController)`

Comment: I wonder what it could be. Cuz' the Hotwire example video had it like that too. reset_form reset_form#reset w/ reset_form_controller.js and it didn't work for me. It honestly drove me crazy because I was trying out all these combinations to no avail, and it only finally worked when I just decided to turn it into a single word. reset reset#reset w/ reset_controller.js

Comment: (tested on 7.0.3.1 fresh app). rename a file then make a change in the renamed file, a new line would do (or restart the server). importmaps are [cached](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails#sweeping-the-cache-in-development-and-test), renaming a file doesn't clear the cache. here is [how to name](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/installing#controller-filenames-map-to-identifiers) controllers. if that's not it, add some details on your setup.

Comment: I'd imagine it's that too-- the wrong naming was cached, so renaming the file didn't clear it. Next time I'll take your advice and restart the server whenever I rename files. Thanks Alex!!

Answer (score 1):

As @Maxence comment, it works fine when we manually register stimulus controller, then there's something wrong with the automatically stimulus controllers registration>

It turns out the `stimulus-rails` gem replace `'_'` to `'-'` when it registers stimulus controllers automatically [code](https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails/blob/main/app/assets/javascripts/stimulus-importmap-autoloader.js#L20)

```js
function registerControllerFromPath(path, under, application) {
  const name = path
    .replace(new RegExp(`^${under}/`), "")
    .replace("_controller", "")
    .replace(/\//g, "--")
    .replace(/_/g, "-") // <---- THIS

    ...
```

So i guess you could name your stimulus controller with `_` like `reset_form_controller.js` and use it with the `-` like `reset-form`

```
{ controller: "reset-form", action: "turbo:submit-end->reset-form#reset" }
```